# I don't know how to do a Soap Request using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I've been trying for hours to do a Request to my Soap Client (SoapUI), reading documentation or recycling code (Yes, sorry), but I am unable to do a simple request.

What I'm trying to do is simple:

- The User inserts a CustomerId and a mail
- The CustomerId goes to my HomeController
- HomeController do a Request to the Soap Client
- The User receives a PDF file to the mail with more information.

That's all.

Some code:

```
 //Receive parameters from Html
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ConexionWS(string customerId, string mail)

 //Connect to client with the authentication
 SoapClient client = new SoapClient(binding, wsdl);
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userN;
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _pasw;
 client.Open();

 XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = GetSoapString(customerId);
 HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(address, _action);
 InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

        private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }

    private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
    }
```

XML where I send the CustomerId:

```
private static XmlDocument GetSoapString(string customerId){
  <urn:ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList>
               <Customerid>"+customerId+"</Customerid>
               <Pedido1></Pedido1>                             
               <Pedido2></Pedido2>            
               <TFacturaMat>                    
                   <item>                            
                      <Food></Food>              
                      <Drink></Drink>              
                      <Souvenir></Souvenir>              
                   </item>                           
               </TFacturaMat>
</urn:ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList>}
```

XML that I expect:

```
<urn:ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList>
               <Customerid>"+customerId+"</Customerid>
               <Pedido1></Pedido1>                             
               <Pedido2></Pedido2>            
               <rests>                    
                   <item>                            
                      <Food>Meal</Food>              
                      <Drink>Water</Drink>              
                      <Souvenir>Nothing</Souvenir>             
                   </item>                           
               </rests>
</urn:ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList>
```

My problems:

- I don´t understand what goes in "action" parameter in CreateWebRequest
- System.Xml.XmlException: ''http' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 33.' in GetSoapString
- I don't know how to use the references that Visual Studio provides me in Reference.cs.

I'm sorry for all this long text. I can't figure it out how to do this. Is my first Web Service and it seems impossible for me.

Answer (score 0):

SOAPAction is the endpoint url.

Like this:

```
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", endpointURL);
```